# Composer install error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, linux, docker, soap, docker-compose

```
i have error when i run composer install command 
docker  problem start is here 
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SOAP} = true ]; then \
  # Install the PHP SOAP extension
  apt-get update -yqq && \
  apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-soap \
;fi

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1
- Installation request for artisaninweb/laravel-soap 0.3.0.9 -> satisfiable by artisaninweb/laravel-soap[0.3.0.9].
- artisaninweb/laravel-soap 0.3.0.9 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.

Answer (score 0):

"the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system".
I would try to install it first.

sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap ( check your version first )

Comment: i checked version and install sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap  but error is not gone